# How does std::setprecision affect general floating-point formatting?

Tags: c++, formatting, precision, iostream, iomanip

I am reading "The C++ standard library - a tutorial and reference" by Nicolai M. Josuttis, Chapter 15: Input/Output Using Stream Classes.
At 15.7.6 Floating-Point Notation, there is a table explaining how the general formatting works for some numbers.

General formatting is the format that is applied when neither fixed nor scientific notation are picked by the developer.

| precision() | 421.0 | 0.0123456789 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 4.2e+02 | 0.012 |
| 6 | 421 | 0.0123457. |

The table shows how a floating-point number is formatted and printed depending on the precision value assigned to the output stream.
For example,
`std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << 421.0 << std::endl;`
Will print `4.2e+02`

I don't understand why for `precision = 2`, in the general format, 0.0123456789 prints 0.012 which shows a number of significant digits greater than the precision value.
I was expecting it to print 0.01 instead of 0.012

Comment: "I don't understand why for precision = 2, in the general format, 0.0123456789 prints 0.012 which shows a number of significants digits higher than the precision value ..." You might not be understanding what a significant digit is. 0.012 has two significant digits. Leading zeros are not significant.

Comment: 0.012 has the same number of significant digits as 1.2e-2. (Why don't you expect   0.012345 for the 6 case?)

Comment: @NathanPierson, thanks for your comment. I didn't understand the meaning of significant digits indeed. Antony gave me a link to better understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works correctly because in this case, precision means the amount of [significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures); it's a mathematical term. E.g. in the number 0.00078 there are 2 significant digits - 78. Not to be confused with the number of digits after decimal point (i.e. number of decimal places).

Comment: Thanks Antony for your answer. I got confused indeed thinking that significant digits were the number of digits after the decimal point.
Marking as resolved.